# Is every nilpotent Lie algebra the nilradical of some Lie algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

If we take $F=\mathbb{C}$ and assume the Lie algebras involved are finite dimensional, is it true that if $\mathfrak{g}$ is nilpotent then it is the nilradical of some other Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$?

Comment: Every nilpotent algebra is its own nilradical.

Comment: If you do not like that, then consider the direct sum of your nilpotent lie algebra and any semisimple one.